# Angular AOT compilation is removing needed code for openlayers

Tags: angular, openlayers, aot

We are using angular 7 with openlayers 5.3. Until now, everything worked fine. For faster initial loading, we have now activated many optimizations during the build, including AOT.
Whenever we do this, the map component stops working with error messages that methods are missing.

As method names are mangled, it's hard to find out what is missing and how to solve it.

My angular-json configuration for the build:

```
{
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": true,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": true,
  "buildOptimizer": true
}
```

Any ideas what might be the reson for this? Or did anyone encounter a similar problem?

Thx
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Angular `AOT` compilator and  `"buildOptimizer": true` You need to check if the openlayers 5.3 is ready to be used with `aot` and  `buildOptimizer` in `true` because `buildOptimizer`  make complex optimizations.

I recomend to you put `buildOptimizer` in `false` and you will **persist the AOT compilation** or try to update that library in a compatible version.